# Garage door won't open unless I hold the wall button down

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

My Genie garage door closes fine on all occasions but it won't open unless I hold the wall button down. This causes real hassle as I can't use my remote opener to open the door as well.

Here is what happening...

When it is fully open or close, left sensor - solid red, right sensor - solid green. If I block the sensors, left sensor blinks red, right sensor stays solid green.

If it is close and I press the wall button and let go, door would open an inch or so and stop. No flash on motor unit light bulb.

If the door is closing and I block the sensors, door stop immediately (does not bounce back up).

What could be the problem/s and how to fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What model is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked again, the spring is broken. Need to call professional.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/64058)

Comment: That's not additional information. I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Your sensors seem to be out of wack. I'D call Genie and ask for tech support and they'll point you in the right direction. Here's their contact information, 
1-800-35-GENIE (354-3643)
Monday – Friday: 9:00 a.m. – 8:00 p.m. EST
Saturday: 10:00 a.m. – 6:00 p.m. EST

Good luck!